# Trying to test "Android Kotlin Fundamentals: 07.2 DiffUtil and data binding with RecyclerView" (Online course )

Tags: android, kotlin

At the tale end of the exercise i.e. **Create binding adapters** when I bind the *<ImageView* in the *.xml* file i.e `kotlin app:sleepImage="@{sleep}` I get the following error: **AAPT: error: attribute sleepImage (aka com.example.android.trackmysleepquality:sleepImage) not found.** outputted by the Build process at run time

Wherelse the attribute `kotlin @BindingAdapter("sleepImage")` has been defined in a *.kt* file and the variable name *sleep* and its type has been defined in the same *.xml* file containing the *<ImageView*. My android studio implementation is 4.1.2. **The question is: How do I get unstack????** I will highly applicate.

**BindingUtils Code (kotlin)**

```
package com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.sleeptracker

import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.R
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.convertDurationToFormatted
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.convertNumericQualityToString
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.database.SleepNight

@BindingAdapter("sleepDurationFormatted")
fun TextView.setSleepDurationFormatted(item : SleepNight?){
    item?.let{
        text = convertDurationToFormatted(item.startTimeMilli,
        item.endTimeMilli, context.resources)
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("sleepQualityString")
fun TextView.setSleepQualityString(item : SleepNight){
    item?.let{
        text = convertNumericQualityToString(item.sleepNight,
                context.resources)
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("sleepImage")
fun ImageView.setSleepImage(item : SleepNight){
    item?.let {
        setImageResource(when (
            item.sleepNight) {
            0 -> R.drawable.ic_sleep_0
            1 -> R.drawable.ic_sleep_1
            2 -> R.drawable.ic_sleep_2
            3 -> R.drawable.ic_sleep_3
            4 -> R.drawable.ic_sleep_4
            5 -> R.drawable.ic_sleep_5
            else -> R.drawable.ic_sleep_active
        })
    }
}
```

**End of BindingUtils Code**

**Start Adapter Code (kotlin)**

```
package com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.sleeptracker

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.R


import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.convertDurationToFormatted
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.convertNumericQualityToString
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.database.SleepNight
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.databinding.ListItemSleepNightBinding
import timber.log.Timber


class SleepNightAdapter: ListAdapter<SleepNight, SleepNightAdapter.ViewHolder>(SleepNightDiffCallback()){

    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = getItem(position)
 
        holder.bind(item)

    }

    class ViewHolder(val binding: ListItemSleepNightBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){ 
        
        fun bind(item: SleepNight) {

            binding.sleep = item
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)


                val binding = ListItemSleepNightBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                Timber.i("onCreateViewHolder Called")


                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder{

        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

}

class SleepNightDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SleepNight>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: SleepNight, newItem: SleepNight): Boolean {
        return oldItem.nightId == newItem.nightId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: SleepNight, newItem: SleepNight): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
```

**End of Adapter Code**

**Start of Layout xml Code (kotlin)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="sleep"
            type="com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.database.SleepNight"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/quality_image"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sleep_5"
            app:sleepImage="@{sleep}"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sleep_length"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/quality_string"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/quality_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/quality_image"
            tools:text="Wednesday"
            app:sleepDurationFormatted="@{sleep}"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quality_string"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/quality_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sleep_length"
            tools:text="Excellent!!!!"
            app:sleepQualityString="@{sleep}"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**End of Layout xml Code**

Comment: can you post the code to make the analysis of the code easier? thanks

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo please find the code as it appears in the 3 separate files, needed to complete the task.